# Open view pager from listview item click

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have a listview with news pouplated with json. 
 Currently `OnItemClickListener` opens a new activity with more detail about the news.
**What i want** now is to **open an activity with a viewpager** which allows users to swipe through the news once they click on one item instead of 
going back to they listview to select a new item. 
It is however that the clicked list item should open the corresponding viewpager item for example if i click item 3 on the listview i see a pager with a news article for item 3 and i can then swipe foward to item 4,5,6 etc or back to item 2,1,0
Below is the code i currently have

**Fragment with news list**

```
public class Feed extends Fragment{
private List<DataModel> mDataList;
private class DataModel {
    private String sFeedTitle;
    private String sFeedDate;
    private String sFeedAuthor;
    private String sFeedTag;
    private String sFeedImage;
    private String sFeedImageAuthor;
    private String sFeed;

    // All getters and setters are here
    }
    @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
       Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
       View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.news_list, container, false);
       return rootView;
}
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);        
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mListView = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.ListView01);
    mProgress = (ProgressBar) getView().findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    makeSampleHttpRequest();
    }

    private void makeSampleHttpRequest() {
    // Get data from the internet and set the model
    }

    private  class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
     private LayoutInflater mInflater;

   public EfficientAdapter(Context context) {
       mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
   }

   public int getCount() {
       return mDataList.size();
   }

   public Object getItem(int position) {
       return position;
   }

   public long getItemId(int position) {
       return position;
   }

   public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
       ViewHolder holder;
        //All view holder code
         mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int pos, long arg3) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), ActivityFeed.class);
                    i.putExtra("FeedTitle", (mDataList.get(pos).getsFeedTitle()));
                    i.putExtra("FeedArticle", (mDataList.get(pos).getsFeed()));
                    i.putExtra("FeedImage", (mDataList.get(pos).getsFeedImage()));
                    i.putExtra("FeedAuthor", (mDataList.get(pos).getsFeedAuthor()));
                    i.putExtra("FeedDate", (mDataList.get(pos).getsFeedDate()));
                    startActivity(i);
                    // This is what is currently doing but instead of this i need to open an activity with a viewpager which allows swiping through all the news in the list. I am familiar with with implimenting a viewpager with static views an content like the one below
                }
       }
    }
}
```

**Viewpager with static views** 
How can i modify this to make it suit my needs

```
public class ViewPagerExample extends FragmentActivity {
private MyAdapter mAdapter;
private ViewPager mPager;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    mAdapter = new MyAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}

public static class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return new Fragment1();
        case 1:
            return new Fragment2();
        case 2:
            return new Fragment3();

        default:
            return null;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: And what the problem?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to set a size of ViewPager pages count. For example, put it to intent :

```
Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), ActivityFeed.class);
i.putExtra("FeedTitle", (mDataList.get(pos).getsFeedTitle()));
i.putExtra("FeedArticle", (mDataList.get(pos).getsFeed()));
i.putExtra("FeedImage", (mDataList.get(pos).getsFeedImage()));
i.putExtra("FeedAuthor", (mDataList.get(pos).getsFeedAuthor()));
i.putExtra("FeedDate", (mDataList.get(pos).getsFeedDate()));
i.putExtra("PagesCount",mDataList.size());
startActivity(i);
```

on Activity side read them :

```
int pagesCount = getIntent().getIntExtra("PagesCount");
```

Initialize adapter.

```
mAdapter = new MyAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), pagesCount);
```

This is what about correct initialization. But i think you need a data too. So read about [Parcelable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) to send a data from one Activity to another. When you got it - no problem here to implement display mechanism.